# What is the relation between conditions $i)$, $ii)$ and $iii)$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, inequality

Let $F\in C^1(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\})$ and let $\varepsilon>0$ small enough. Let $a<1$ and consider the assumptions:
$$i)\quad F(s)\ge \frac{1}{s^a}\quad\mbox{ for $|s|<\varepsilon$};$$
$$ii)\quad F(s)\ge -\frac{1}{s^a}\quad\mbox{ for $|s|<\varepsilon$};$$
$$iii)\quad F^{\prime}(s)\ge \frac{1}{s^2}\quad\mbox{ for $|s|<\varepsilon$}.$$

As an exercise, I need to understand what is the relation between them.

I tried this: If I take $F^{\prime}(s) =\frac{1}{s^2}$, thus $F(s)=-\frac{1}{s}$ and then $i)$ is not satisfied but $ii)$ is satisfied. So $iii)\implies ii)$ but $iii)\nRightarrow i)$.

Could someone please help me to find some other examples/counterexamples like that? Or please give some hints to understand how they works?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not true that $\ iii)\Rightarrow ii)\ $.   Let $\ a=\frac{1}{2}\ $,$\ \epsilon=2\ $ and $\ F(s)={-}10-\frac{1}{s}\ $. Then $\ F'(s)=\frac{1}{s^2}\ge \frac{1}{s^2}\ $ for $\ |s|<\epsilon\ $, so $\ iii)\ $ is satisfied.  But $\ F(1)=$$\,{-}10\ $,  while $\ {-}\frac{1}{1^a}=-1\ $, so $\ F(s)\not\ge{-}\frac{1}{s^a}\ $ for at least one $\ s\ $ with $\ |s|<\epsilon\ $—namely, $\ s=1\ $.  Therefore $\ ii)\ $ is *not* satisfied.  Therefore it can't be true that $\ iii)\Rightarrow ii)\ $.

The problem with your argument is that $\ F(s)={-}\frac{1}{s}\ $ isn't the only function that satisfies $\ iii)\ $. To show that $\ iii)\Rightarrow ii)\ $, you need to show that *every* function which satisfies $\ iii)\ $ also satisfies $\ ii)\ $, but since there exist functions that satisfy $\ iii)\ $ but don't satisfy $\ ii)\ $, this is impossible.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you integrate with an example which allows to say that $iii)\nRightarrow i)$? Anyway, it is possible to find at least one function which satisfies both $iii)$ and $i)$? Thank you in aadvance.

Comment: The best way to say thanks is to simply upvote or accept an answer. @C.Bishop

Comment: @ryang I am just asking to integrate the answer with an example for the other case, since, to me, the answer seems not complete so far. Clearly, I will accept his answer.

Comment: lonza leggiera, you say that you take $a=1/2$ but then you consider $F(s)=-10-1/s$. What am I missing?

Comment: Yes, you shouldn't accept any answer unless you you think it clearly answers your question.  In $\ ii)\ $ you require $\ F(s)\ge\frac{1}{s^a}\ $ for $\ |s|<\epsilon\ $.  If $\ F(s)=-10-\frac{1}{s}\ $, $\ a=\frac{1}{2}\ $ and $\ \epsilon=2\ $ then $\ s=1\ $ satisfies $\ |s|<\epsilon\ $, but $\ F(s)=-10-\frac{1}{1}=-11\ $ and $\ {-}\frac{1}{s^a}={-}\frac{1}{1^a}=-1 $, so it's not true that $\ F(s)\ge{-}\frac{1}{s^a}\ $ for that value of $\ s\ $ and therefore $\ F\ $ doesn't satisfy $\ ii)\ $.

Comment: My above remark is neutral, and was made while the question had no upvote.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera, unfortunately, I continue not to understand why you say you take $a=1/2$ and then write $F(s)=-10-1/s$. Moreover, condition $ii)$ is $F(s)\ge -\frac{1}{s^a}$.

Comment: I'm simply choosing $\ F\ $  to satisfy $\ iii)\ $ but not  $\ ii)\ $.  Note that, as currently written, your $\ iii)\ $ says $\ F'(s)\ge\frac{1}{s^{\color{red}2}}\ $ for $\ |s|<\epsilon\ $, and has no dependence whatever on $\ a\ $.   If I choose $\ F(s)=-10-\frac{1}{s}\ $, then $\ F'(s)=\frac{1}{s^2}\ $, so this $\ F\ $ satisfies $\ iii)\ $, regardless of what the value of $\ a\ $ is. Is the exponent $\ \color{red}{2}\ $ currently appearing in the statement of $\ iii)\ $ perhaps a typo?  Did you instead want it to be some function of $\ a\ $?

Comment: Note also that your condition $\ ii)\ $ currently says $\ F(s)\ge{-}\frac{1}{s^a}\ \ \ \color{red}{\text{for }\ |s|<\epsilon}$, so $\ F\ $ fails to satisfy $\ ii)\ $ if there is *any* $\ s\ $ in the interval $\ ({-}\epsilon,\epsilon)\ $ such that $\ F(s)<{-}\frac{1}{s^a}\ $.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera no, it is correct. Thank you.